# Does this look like an unacceptable level of wear on a steering shaft coupler

Tags: steering, inspection

Working on my 1986 Dodge van I noticed this part, which I believe is the steering shaft coupler, showing what I think is excessive wear.

My haynes manual doesn't provide any info about inspecting/servicing the shaft coupler, and there is no photo, so I don't have anything to compare this to.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the measured play? All I see is a split dust cover.

Comment: Does it move when you turn the steering wheel?  What symptoms are you experiencing?

Comment: It's out at a storage lot, and I noticed this when I was packing up for the day so I didn't dig further.  The steering on this thing has always been sloppy, there is several degrees of play in the steering wheel and it tends to wander in the lane a bit, but I have no problem driving straight or maintaining control. Conversations with other owners of these Dodge vans leads me to believe the handling I experience is typical (or even on the better side) of what these rigs feel like.  So in this case I'm just trying to be proactive.

Comment: You usually won't see any play in the steering coming for this part of the system. Usually, play comes from the tires, alignment, or worn parts in the suspension.

Comment: based on the comments it sounds like what I'm seeing here is really just the lack of a dust cover, and we can't actually determine anything about the coupler one way or the other based on these images except that it isn't obviously visually failing/broken.